# Assign macro to button that executes the macro on the designated row of where the button is located.=

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with VBA with a code where a button pressed executes the assigned macro, where the macro is assigned to execute where the button was pressed.

Basically, I created a tracking workbook where I usually input a new "task" via macros, this adds a new row and a new button by the row.

The problem I am having is that I want to use the same macro (once task is completed, it cuts and pastes into a "history" sheet) for the specific row a button is located.

How can I do this? Is this actually possible? Below is the step by step of my thoughts

- Press "AddTask" button = creates a new row with data input from user with "Completed" button on the same row
- Tie the "Completed" button to the row that was added so when Macro "Complete" runs, it will only run specifically to the row of where the button was pushed.

This will help because maybe I finish task# 53 (row 53) first before task# 41 (row 41), so I want to delete row 53.

Macros and VBA is what I need.

Comment: SO is not a code demanding site. Basically you can have 2 buttons (1 for AddTask, 1 for Completed), have them dynamically moved via `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, and possibly have "Completed" hidden if not Added to Task before, and hide "AddTask" if already added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.Caller` to determine what called a Sub.  In the case of a Form button it returns the name of the button as a string.  (Refer online help for full details).  Then use the ActiveSheet Buttons collection to retrieve the button, and TopLeftCell to get the location on the sheet.  Error handling is required to gracefully exit if the Sub is called from other sources.

```
Sub Complete()
    Dim rng As Range

    If TypeName(Application.Caller) <> "String" Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.EntireRow
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' rng now refers to the row that the clicked button is on
    '... rest of your code

End Sub
```

Comment: @John which part is confusing?